# AS3 hitTestPoint accuracy is delayed by one frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

While I'm doing my current project, I found out that hitTestPoint accuracy is one frame delayed as soon as I moved the object. So if object A is moved to a completely new and faraway position, hitTestPoint performed on that object will return false. To illustrate this, I've made a quick experiment using the most basic logic:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.Event;

var me:Sprite = new Sprite();
var g:Graphics = me.graphics;
g.beginFill( 0xFF0000 );
g.drawRect( -10, -10, 20, 20 );
g.endFill();
addChild( me );

trace( "Hit test at (0,0) while object is at (" + me.x + "," + me.y + ") = " + me.hitTestPoint( 0, 0, true ) );

me.x = 300;
me.y = 300;

trace( "\n>>>>>>>>>> WHERE DID THE OBJECT GO? >>>>>>>>>>" );
trace( "Hit test at (0,0) while object is at (" + me.x + "," + me.y + ") = " + me.hitTestPoint( 0, 0, true ) );
trace( "Hit test at (150,150) while object is at (" + me.x + "," + me.y + ") = " + me.hitTestPoint( 150, 150, true ) );
trace( "Hit test at (300,300) while object is at (" + me.x + "," + me.y + ") = " + me.hitTestPoint( 300, 300, true ) );
trace( ">>>>>>>>>> WHERE DID THE OBJECT GO? >>>>>>>>>>\n" );

removeChild( me );
addChild( me );

trace( "After remove/addChild, hit test at (300,300) while object is at (" + me.x + "," + me.y + ") = " + me.hitTestPoint( 300, 300, true ) );
```

And here's the results:

```
Hit test at (0,0) while object is at (0,0) = true

>>>>>>>>>> WHERE DID THE OBJECT GO? >>>>>>>>>>
Hit test at (0,0) while object is at (300,300) = false
Hit test at (150,150) while object is at (300,300) = false
Hit test at (300,300) while object is at (300,300) = false
>>>>>>>>>> WHERE DID THE OBJECT GO? >>>>>>>>>>

After remove/addChild, hit test at (300,300) while object is at (300,300) = true
```

I found out that the hitTestPoint works again after removing and adding the child back to the stage. But also hitTestPoint works on the next frame.

Anyone has encountered this same thing so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is happening due to the way flash handles Display Objects.
My **guess** is that the moment you call

```
addChild(me);
```

"addChild" forces flash to draw 'me'.
but when you move 'me' it using x and y parameters flash waits for the frame to complete before redrawing the graphics.

Again i am **guessing** if you want to enforce flash to redraw immediately

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.events.Event;

var me:Sprite = new Sprite();
var g:Graphics = me.graphics;
var myIndex:int;
g.beginFill( 0xFF0000 );
g.drawRect( -10, -10, 20, 20 );
g.endFill();
addChild( me );

me.x = 300;
me.y = 300;

addChild(me);
```

Do not use this hack unless there is no way around it as it can slow down your application.
Again I could not check if i am correct as i do not have flash on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm what chandings said about the time when flash updates the object's positions on stage, but the explanation can be corrected and expanded. Flash indeed has a fixed framerate, and display updates follow this timeline. But the game logic can go faster or slower than the rendering speed. If you call `addChild(me)` it will not update the position immediately, but also on the start of the next frame.

So you must chose to go with a fixed time step or a variable time step. Independent of the choice you make, it's better to use events like `OnEnterFame` to manage the time step than to depend on the flash player to update your logic.

I wrote [an answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29583/2d-animation-smoothness-delta-time-vs-kinematics/29600#29600) to a similar problem on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) and the thread also has some useful links:

- [Timing & Motion](http://flashpunk.net/2011/05/timing-motion/)
- [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

And here's another useful thread that's language independent: [Fixed time step vs Variable time step](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/fixed-time-step-vs-variable-time-step)